# iOS 7 - text in custom tableViewCell content getting cut

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have been trying to figure this out for the past couple of hours but to no avail. I have a custom tableViewCell class which I use for my tableViewCells. I have 3 labels and 2 textFields in the custom class. Here is my `SearchResultTableViewCell.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchResultTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *price;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *discount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *quantity;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *discountInput;

@end
```

The text Labels are populated from database entries. The issue I'm having right now is when the `itemName` is too long, it gets cut in the display. I have tried setting the Lines property of the Label in the storyboard to 3 lines but it does not work. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement multiple lines in a label? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Yes. I unchecked it and I'll test in now.

Answer (score 0):

If you set numberOfLines to 0 (and the label to text Wrap), the label will automatically wrap and use as many of lines as needed.

cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTextWrap;

If you're editing a UILabel in IB, you can enter multiple lines of text by pressing alt-return to get a line break - return will finish editing.

Comment: This does not work. I set the Lines to 0 and the Line Breaks to Word Wrap and what happened was the entries were cut instead of having ellipses.

Comment: try doing the text wrap thing and see the changes i have made to my answer.

Comment: And I place that in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 0):

In your **CustomTableViewCell.m**

```
    self.itemName.numberOfLines = 0; // change to 0 to support multiple lines
    self.itemName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    CGRect frame = self.itemName.frame; // cache the frame of your item name label
    CGFloat itemWidth = frame.size.width; // keep the width to a variable
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(itemWidth, 2000); // define your constraint, unlimited height, and the width will be the original width
    CGSize size = [self.itemName.text sizeWithFont:self.itemName.font constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:self.itemName.lineBreakMode]; // get the size that fit your content
    size.width = itemWidth; // use back the original width
    frame.size = size; // update the size to the frame cached just now
    self.itemName.frame = frame; // update the item name label frame
```